# How to prove that triangle inscribed in another triangle (were both have one shared side) have lower perimeter?

Tags: proof-writing, triangles

This question looks really simple, but to my (and my co-workers) frustration we were not able to prove this in any way. I tried all triangle formulas known to me but I feel I'm missing the point, and proof will be or much simpler or much more complicated than what I tried.

So, the question:

Given a triangle ABC and point P inside that triangle, prove that for triangle APB the following inequality holds:
|AB| + |BC| > |AP| + |PC|

(Actually it doesn't matter for me if it's > or >=).

Comment: 'Inscribed' means P is on the perimeter of ABC, and this special case is simple to prove. Your problem appears to be asking after the more general problem where P may be in the interior of ABC, though. Could you clarify which you want?

Comment: Yes, what I mean was that P is in the interior of ABC, I just used wrong word then. Thanks for pointing it out, I'm not native speaker and looks like google translate tricked me out with terminology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is really an elementary proof of a more general result: if one polygon fits within the other (boundaries may touch) then its perimeter is smaller than that of the bigger polygon

http://www.cut-the-knot.org/m/Geometry/PerimetersOfTwoConvexPolygons.shtml

The idea is that the sides of the small polygon may be extended, trimming the bigger polygon until the sides of one are on the sides of the other so that side-by-side inequalities could be summed up to get an inequality for the perimeters

Answer (score 3):

One way to see that this must be true is to look at the ellipse through $B$ with foci $A$ and $C$. The interior of this ellipse is precisely all those point $P$ such that $|AP| + |PC| < |AB| + |BC|$. And if $P$ is inside the triangle, then it is inside the ellipse too.

Comment: Thanks! Honestly I was thinking about the same proof today, but I was not sure if it's correct. To be more precise I was not sure if your third sentence doesn't need to be proven first, and that led me to nowhere as you can imagine...

Answer (score 3):

A late answer but I think it's the simplest...

Extend AP to intersect BC, call the intersection point D.

Using triangle inequality |AB| + |BD| > |AD|, similarly |PD| + |DC| > |PC|.  Adding two inequalities:

|AB| + |BD| + |PD| + |DC| > |AD| + |PC|

|AB| + |BC| + |PD| > |AD| + |PC|

|AB| + |BC| > |AD| - |PD| + |PC| = |AP| + |PC|

[image]

Comment: good reasoning thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is a special case of "Archimedes' axiom", that if one convex curve $\gamma_1$ is inside another ($\gamma_2$), then $\gamma_1$ is shorter than $\gamma_2.$ Archimedes needed this to justify his computing the perimeter of a circle by inscribed/circumscribed polygons, and could not prove it, so made it an axiom. In general, this is a nontrivial fact, in this case it is a tedious computation (if you don't want to use the general machine).

**EDIT** the most elegant proof is via Crofton's formula, which says that the length of a convex curve is equal (up to normalizing constant) to the measure of the lines which intersect the interior -- that measure is obviously monotonic under containment...

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at different axioms but I wasn't able to find that one. Looks like it matches my problem perfectly. But I'm curious how it relates to what TonyK wrote. If it's axiom, then shouldn't it be unprovable? So is what TonyK wrote not real proof or is there something more which I'm missing?

Comment: @kuki Archimedes made it an axiom because _he_ could not prove it, and it seemed obvious. But now, we know more, and _can_ prove it.

Answer (score 2):

Since $P$ is inside $\triangle ABC$, the convex hull span by the three vertices $A$, $B$, $C$, there exists 3 numbers $\alpha, \beta, \gamma \ge 0$ such that

$$\alpha+\beta+\gamma = 1\quad\text{ and }\quad 
\vec{P} = \alpha \vec{A} + \beta \vec{B} + \gamma \vec{C}$$

This implies
$$
|AP| = |(1-\alpha)\vec{A} - (1-\alpha-\gamma)\vec{B} - \gamma\vec{C}|
     = |(1-\alpha)(\vec{A}-\vec{B}) + \gamma (\vec{B}-\vec{C})|\\
     \le (1-\alpha) |AB| + \gamma |BC|
$$ and $$
|CP| = |-\alpha \vec{A} - (1-\alpha-\gamma)\vec{B} + (1-\gamma)\vec{C}|
     = |\alpha (\vec{B}-\vec{A}) + (1-\gamma)(\vec{C}-\vec{B})|\\
     \le \alpha |AB| + (1-\gamma)|BC|
$$
Summing these two inequalities immediately gives us $|AP| + |CP| \le |AB| + |BC|$.

Since numbers like $\alpha$ are ratios of distance of $P$ to $BC$ versus that of $A$ to $BC$, it is easy to translate above vector based inequalities to a pure geometric proof.

Construct a line through $P$ parallel to $BC$ and let it intersect $AB$ at $D$. Construct another line through $P$ parallel to $AB$ and let it intersect $BC$ at $E$. It is easy to
see $|BE| = |PD|$ and $|BD| = |EP|$. Apply triangle inequalities to $\triangle APD$ and $\triangle CPE$, we have

$$|AP| + |CP| \le \Big(|AD| + |PD|\Big) + \Big(|CE| + |EP|\Big) 
= \Big(|AD| + |BE|\Big) + \Big(|CE| + |BD|\Big)\\
= \Big(|AD| + |DB|\Big) + \Big(|CE| + |BE|\Big) = |AB| + |BC|$$

[image: Inscribed triangle]

Answer (score 0):

Another variant on above. It takes 3 applications of the triangle inequality but I like how symmetrical it looks.

- Add a segment DE between AB and BC that intersects P.
- By the triangle inequality (1) $|BD| + |BE| > |DE|$ or $|BD| + |BE| > |DP| + |EP|$
- Then again on the two middle triangles: $|AE| + |EP| > |AP|$ and $|CD| + |DP| > |CP|$
- So add $ |AE| + |CD|$ to both sides of (1) to get: $|AB| + |BC| > (|CD| + |DP|) + (|AE| + |EP|) > |CP| + |AP|$

[image: tri inequality aux line]