# Proving $BD+CD<AB+AC$

Tags: geometry, inequality, triangles

Consider the triangle below with $D$ as an interior point.

[image]

We need to prove that $BD+CD<AB+AC$

My try:

I extended $BD$ to meet $AC$ at $F$:

I also joined $AD$ as shown below:

[image]

Now in $\Delta ADC$ and $\Delta ADB$ by triangle inequality we have:
$$AD+DC>AC$$ and
$$AD+BD>AB$$

Adding both we get $$BD+CD>AB+AC-2AD$$

I need help from here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Given a point $x$ inside the triangle $ΔABC$, prove that $XA+XB &lt; CA + CB$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3047111/given-a-point-x-inside-the-triangle-%ce%94abc-prove-that-xaxb-ca-cb). Found using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24BD%2BCD%5Clt%20AB%2BAC%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Atriangle&p=1). Also, a comment there links to [How to prove that triangle inscribed in another triangle (were both have one shared side) have lower perimeter?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/613296/602049) which has $6$ answers.

Answer (score 1):

My try:

$BD+CD<BF+CF<AB+AC$

Answer (score 0):

Geometrically, area of the triangle BCD is smaller than the area of the triangle ABC, since D is an interior point of the triangle ABC.

Hence, the circumference of BCD must be smaller than the circumference of the triangle ABC.

This shows that BC + CD + BD < AB + BC + AC

In other words, BD + CD < BC + AC.

A quick geometric proof!